# Suggestions for a jQuery image zoom

Tags: jquery, image, zooming

I am looking for a light jQuery image zoom when hovering or clicking on the image. It is very important that the image is loaded after hover or after clicking on it and not before. The reason for this is to decrease the initial page load as much as possible.

Any suggestions for some good scripts?

Comment: Are you looking for IE8 and below too ?

Comment: Well, if it works bellow IE8, it's even better, but it is not a IE8 requirement

Comment: I would use CSS3 animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of existing jquery image sliders. A personal favorite is tn3. Or existing things like lightbox. Otherwise, if you simply want to zoom the image in place on the page (no popup or widgit type things) then you'll want to look into image scaling methods. Or perhaps the best new age way would be to use a CSS3 scaling animation.

**EDIT**
This is a sample of how you might want to use it to prevent loading until later.

HTML:

```
<a id='image_to_load' href='' rel='lightbox'> </a>
```

Javascript (or Jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image = $('#image_to_load');
    image.onclick = function(e){image.href = '/path/to/image'; //add lightbox handler too};
});
```

Comment: Lightbox seems good. Do you know, does it loads the image after clicking on it?

Comment: I don't think lightbox is involved with the loading of the image - it simply provides some features after clicked. But, you can load the image yourself.